# ¿Qué es una instancia en base de datos?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, datos

He estado investigando sobre esto y todas las paginas tienen las misma definición, necesito una explicación mejor de entender.

La definición que he visto es esta:

Una instancia de Motor de base de datos es una copia del ejecutable de sqlservr.exe que se ejecuta como un servicio de sistema operativo. Cada instancia administra varias bases de datos del sistema y una o varias bases de datos de usuario. Cada equipo puede ejecutar varias instancias de Motor de base de datos. Las aplicaciones se conectan a la instancia para realizar el trabajo en una base de datos administrada por la instancia.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! tienen la misma definicion que es cual?

Comment: Si todas las páginas tienen la misma definición ¿Qué te hace pensar que aquí te darán una distinta? En especial si no pones cual definición es la que ya tienes.

Comment: @LuisCazares, Esta es la definición que me aparece: Una instancia de Motor de base de datos es una copia del ejecutable de sqlservr.exe que se ejecuta como un servicio de sistema operativo. Cada instancia administra varias bases de datos del sistema y una o varias bases de datos de usuario. Cada equipo puede ejecutar varias instancias de Motor de base de datos. Las aplicaciones se conectan a la instancia para realizar el trabajo en una base de datos administrada por la instancia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una instancia es la aplicación que gestiona las bases de datos. Esta viene empaquetada como un servicio de windows. Y no tiene interfaz de usuario.

[image: Instancias]

Si observas la captura de pantalla, en mi equipo, yo tengo 3 instancias.

Puedes tener todas las que quieras, siendo el límite, los recursos de la misma.

Y de las versiones que quieras. (Aquí entran en juego los tipos y licencias de las que dispongas. Por ejemplo, las express son gratuitas y puedes tener las que te apetezca).

Cada instancia, gestiona sus propias bases de datos, siendo elementos únicos dentro de la instancia. Por ejemplo, podemos tener una base de datos de nombre A en la instancia SQL2017. Una base llamada A en la instancia SQL2019 y una base llamada A en la instancia SQLEXPRESS.

Cada aplicación cliente, se puede conectar a estas instancias para gestionar su base de datos específica. Aunque cuando hacemos una consulta en la tabla clientes de la base de datos A de la instancia SQL2019, nuestro código dice:

```
Select * from clientes;
```

Realmente esto por debajo se gestiona como:

```
Select * from [SQL2019].[A].dbo.clientes;
```

Lo que se conoce como nombre cualificado de 4 partes. O lo que es lo mismo. Nombre de instancia. Nombre de Base de datos. Esquema propietario. Nombre de tabla.

Todo lo que hacemos en nuestros programas cliente o en nuestros gestores de base de datos, realmente se traduce en sentencias SQL que el software que gestiona, envía al motor.

Cuando te conectas con las aplicaciones o con cualquiera de los posibles gestores, la ventana de conexión, te pide el nombre del servidor "server name", que corresponde en este caso, con el nombre del servidor (nombre de mi equipo) y el nombre de la instancia.

[image: Conexión]

Answer (score 0):

te doy una idea para ver si te sirve :
Instancia = vehículo
Base de Datos = Pasajeros.
digamos que un vehículo puede llevar a tantos pasajeros como potencia tenga su motor.
seria lo mismo que decir: una instancia puede gestionar tantas bases de datos como capacidad de hardware tengas.
Cuando creas un instancia. lo que estas haciendo es creando un (Vehículo) ese vehículo se encargara de Transportar a los pasajeros que le asignes, (Bases de datos)
por eso cuando creas la base propiamente dicha, Tenes que decirle sobre que instancia se hace.  algo asi como decir quienes estan designados a que transporte.
Me pareció que ese concepto es el que querias entender, si no lo es te pido disculpa